# putting multiple value in one series in a chart in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to put income and expenses in a chart where i have two series.
First series total income and second one total expenses, and put in each series 2 values expected and actual.
I know hot to put 1 value in a series.
This is my code:

```
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = db.GetRecords("bacci.income_table", "SUM(Amount_income_table), year(Date_income_table)",
                                                     "year(Date_income_table)='" & ComboBoxYears.SelectedItem.ToString & "'",,
                                                     "year(Date_income_table)")
While reader.Read
    ChartTotalSummary.Series("Total Income").Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("year(Date_income_table)"), reader.GetString("SUM(Amount_income_table)"))

End While

db.Disconnect()
db.Connect()
reader = db.GetRecords("bacci.expenses_table", "SUM(Amount_expenses_table), year(Date_expenses_table)", "year(Date_expenses_table)='" & ComboBoxYears.SelectedItem.ToString & "'",, "year(Date_expenses_table)")

While reader.Read
    ChartTotalSummary.Series("Total Expenses").Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("year(Date_expenses_table)"), reader.GetString("SUM(Amount_expenses_table)"))

End While

db.Disconnect()
db.Connect()

reader = db.GetRecords("bacci.estimated_income_table", "SUM(estimated_amount)", "estimated_year='" & ComboBoxYears.SelectedItem.ToString & "'",, "estimated_year")

While reader.Read
    'ChartTotalSummary.Series.
    ChartTotalSummary.Series("Total Income").Points.AddXY(reader.GetString("year(estimated_year)"), reader.GetString("SUM(estimated_amount)"))
End While
```

When i put estimated income in series total income i get this error:

> could not find specific column in results

I want the result to be like this:

[image]